# My generated french word duplicates? When it shouldn't be

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I've sorted this but now it's came back on... I've tried changing the for loops but it still seems to generate duplicate French words. It's suppose to not show the french word twice in the application run.

#### My jsFiddle is an exact replica:

http://jsfiddle.net/jamesw1/w8p7b6p3/17/

### Javascript:

```
    //James Wainwright's Mobile Apps Assignment
    //Arrays of french and english words.
    var
    RanNumbers = new Array(6),
        foreignWords = ['un', 'deux', 'trois', 'quatre', 'cinq', 'six', 'sept', 'huit', 'neuf', 'dix', 'onze', 'douze', 'treize', 'quatorze', 'quinze', 'seize', 'dix-sept', 'dix-huit', 'dix-neuf', 'vingt', 'vingt et un', 'vingt-deux', 'vingt-trois', 'vingt-quatre', 'vingt-cinq', 'vingt-six', 'vingt-sept', 'vingt-huit', 'vingt-neuf', 'trente'],
        translate = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine', 'ten', 'eleven', 'twelve', 'thirteen', 'fourteen', 'fifteen', 'sixteen', 'seventeen', 'eighteen', 'nineteen', 'twenty', 'twenty-one', 'twenty-two', 'twenty-three', 'twenty-four', 'twenty-five', 'twenty-six', 'twenty-seven', 'twenty-eight', 'twenty-nine', 'thirty'],
        number = Math.floor((Math.random() * 30)),
        output = '',
        correctAns = translate[number];

    //Generate random numbers and make sure they aren't the same as each other.
    function wordGen() {
    for (var h = 0; h < RanNumbers.length; h++) {
        var temp = 0;
        do {
            temp = Math.floor(Math.random() * 30);
            while(temp==correctAns){
              temp = Math.floor(Math.random() * 30);
            }
        } while (RanNumbers.indexOf(temp) > -1);
        RanNumbers[h] = temp;

    }
} 

        //Call the previous function
        wordGen();

    //Create dynamic select menu using for loop. This loop runs once (on document load)
    document.getElementById('generatedWord').textContent = foreignWords[number];
    var correctAnswerIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);

        //If it's 0...Change it.
        if(correctAnswerIndex == 0)
        {
            correctAnswerIndex++;   
        }

        //Create a select menu of the options...Add the correct answer randomly into the menu.
        var guess = "<select name='guesses' id='guesses'>";
        for (var i = 1; i < RanNumbers.length; i++) {
            //This randomizes where the correct answer will be.
            if(i == correctAnswerIndex)
                 guess += '<option value="'+i+'">' + correctAns + '</option>';
            else
                 guess += "<option selected='selected' value='" + i + "'>" + translate[RanNumbers[i]] + "</option>";

        }
        guess += "</select>";

    //Output the previous.
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = guess;
    numGuessed = document.getElementById('guesses').value;

    function arrayValueIndex(arr, val) {
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[i] === val) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    //Declare variables 'outside' the onclick function so it ensures they work correctly.
    var numGames = 5;
    var numGuesses = 1;
    var correct = 0;
    var wrong = 0;
    var prevNumber;
    var counter = 0;
    var outputted = '';

    //Create arrays that will hold the options they chose, the correct answer for that particular question, and ofcourse the generated word.
    var guessedList = new Array(6);
    var correctList = new Array(6);
    var wordGenerated = new Array(6);

    //On click, Get new word, Calculate how many they got right/wrong, Show the user what they entered, show them the correct values they should've guessed and more...
    document.getElementById('submitAns').onclick = function () {

    //Declare variables for function.
        prevNumber = number;
        number = Math.floor((Math.random() * 30)),
        output = '',
        correctAns = translate[number];
        document.getElementById('numGuess').innerHTML = "Question #" + numGuesses;

    //Check if guess is right or wrong, if right add 1 to correct pile..Visa versa.
         var
        genWord = document.getElementById('generatedWord').textContent,
            select = document.getElementById('guesses'),
            selectedText = select.options[select.selectedIndex].text;
        prevNumber === arrayValueIndex(translate, selectedText) ? correct++ : wrong++;


    function wordGen() {
    for (var j = 0; j < RanNumbers.length; j++) {
        var temp = 0;
        do {
            temp = Math.floor(Math.random() * 30);
            while(temp==correctAns){
              temp = Math.floor(Math.random() * 30);
            }
        } while (RanNumbers.indexOf(temp) > -1);
        RanNumbers[j] = temp;

    }
}

        //Generate a word here. ( call wordGen() ) 
        wordGen();

        //Create dynamic select menu for options they have to choose from.
        document.getElementById('generatedWord').textContent = foreignWords[number];

        //Generate a random number, so that the 'Correct' answer can be randomly put in a position in the select menu. (It won't always be in the same position...It changes depending on the random number
        var correctAnswerIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);

        //If it's 0...Change it.
        if(correctAnswerIndex == 0)
        {
            correctAnswerIndex++;   
        }

        //Create a select menu of the options...Add the correct answer randomly into the menu.
        var guess = "<select name='guesses' id='guesses'>";
        for (var i = 1; i < RanNumbers.length; i++) {
            //This randomizes where the correct answer will be.
            if(i == correctAnswerIndex)
                 guess += '<option value="'+i+'">' + correctAns + '</option>';
            else
                 guess += "<option selected='selected' value='" + i + "'>" + translate[RanNumbers[i]] + "</option>";

        }
        guess += "</select>";

        //Outputting to the html page.
        document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = guess;
        numGuessed = document.getElementById('guesses').value;

        function arrayValueIndex(arr, val) {
            for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                if (arr[i] === val) {
                    return i;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
        //Checking of the answers below, Accumilating correct and wrong answer. 
        //Count number of guesses
        numGuesses++;
        //Counter for placing guessed, correct and foreign word into there arrays.
        counter++;

        wordGenerated[counter] = foreignWords[number];
        guessedList[counter] = document.getElementById('guesses').options[select.selectedIndex].text;
        correctList[counter] = translate[number];

       //Once the application has finished...It will produce the following output.
        if (numGuesses == 6) {
            document.getElementById('generatedWord').innerHTML = "<span style='font-size:12px;color:red';>Please click for a new game when ready!</span><br /><p>You got " + wrong + " questions wrong " + "<br />You got " + correct + " questions correct";
                $('#submitAns').hide();
                outputted = "<table>";
                for(var d=1;d<wordGenerated.length;d++){
                    outputted += "<tr><td><span id='guessedWord'>Question " + d + ":</td> <td>Generated word: " + wordGenerated[d] + "</td>    <td>Guessed Word: " + guessedList[d] + "</td>   <td><span id='correctWord'>Correct Word: " + correctList[d] + "</span></td></td>";
                }
                outputted += "</table>";
                outputted += "<style type='text/css'>#hint{ display:none; }</style>";
                //Output it to the html page.
                    document.getElementById('details').innerHTML = outputted;
        }
    };
    document.getElementById('hint').onclick = function () {
        alert(correctAns.charAt(0));
    };
```

### Html:

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1" data-add-back-btn="true">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>James' Translation Guessing Game</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content" class="main">  
        <h2 id="display" style="color:rgba(204,51,204,1);">Guess what the generated french word translates to in English!</h2><br />

        <!-- What question we're upto -->
        <h2 id="numGuess">Question #</h2 >

        <!-- The generated French Word  Aswell as end of app details-->
        <div align="center" class="frenchWord" style="position:">

        <!--Generated french word details-->
             <div style="background-color:rgba(51,51,51,0.5);border-radius:4px 10px 2px;"align="center"  id="generatedWord"></div>
             <br />
             <br />
   <!-- Show the user there guessed answers, correct and foreign word -->
             <div id="details"></div>
        </div>

        <!-- Select menu output -->
        <div align="center" id="output"></div>

        <a href="#" id="hint"><img id="hintImg" style="" src="images/hint.png" alt="Hint" /></a>

        <!-- Buttons, Call Functions -->
        <button type="button" style='opacity:0.5' id="submitAns" onClick="translate();">Check</button>
        <input type="button" value="New Game" onClick="document.location.reload(true)">
             <script>
             //Simple animation
             $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#generatedWord").animate({
                    opacity: 0.8,
                    margin: "40px 0px 100px 0px",
                    width: "20%",
                    padding: "30px",
                }, 1500 );
});
</script>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>James Wainwright</h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might do it. Before assigning a number to the `RanNumbers` array I delete it from the original `RanNumbers` array to prevent duplication. It might make more sense to just maintain a separate array of numbers to be used in the questions but I tried to change as little as possible.

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w8p7b6p3/19/)

```
function wordGen() {
    for (var h = 0; h < RanNumbers.length; h++) {
        var temp = 0;
        do {
            temp = Math.floor(Math.random() * RanNumbers.length);
            while(temp==correctAns){
              temp = Math.floor(Math.random() * RanNumbers.length);
                delete(RanNumbers.indexOf(temp)); // delete it so we can add it down below
            }
        } while (RanNumbers.indexOf(temp) > -1);
        RanNumbers[h] = temp;

    }
```

Comment: this works most of the time, it certainly reduces the times is duplicates!